# How does CPU differentiate REP and REPE instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86

According to [this](http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/x86asmref.html#rep) manual, `REP` and `REPE` instructions have different behaviour, but the same opcode `F3`.

How does CPU differentiate this two commands, if they both have the same opcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`REP` and `REPE` are [prefixes](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0240_prefix.htm), not instructions. Some instructions accept the `REPE` prefix. Others accept `REP`. The ISA was designed so that no instruction accepts both, so the problem does not arise.